# Is there a way to locally include Adobe Flash with Mozilla Firefox, Portable Edition?

Tags: firefox, flash, portable-apps

Is there any way to locally include Adobe Flash with my Mozilla Firefox, Portable Edition? I'm using the one from [portableapps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)

I need to do this so I can use my browser in another computer without installing flash. Or when I can't install Flash because I don't have administrator rights.

The guide in [this](http://portableapps.com/support/firefox_portable#plugins) page is outdated and no longer works with the latest version as of right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

There are two ways to do this.

**Method 1:**

Following this guide: [Flash player 11.9.900.117 for portable browsers (32 and 64 bits)](http://notepad.patheticcockroach.com/2243/flash-11-for-portable-browsers-32-and-64-bits/)

1. Download the most recent [Flash version as zip.](http://uploaded.net/file/fp9uaj9j)
   The above blog author seems to update his post if new Flash versions appear
2. Extract all files to `../FirefoxPortable/Data/plugins`
3. In Firefox, open `about:config`  and set `plugins.load_appdir_plugins` to true (if not already is)

Test system was

1. Windows 7 x64
2. Firefox Portable (Aurora channel, 27.0a2, 2013-11-03)
3. Flash Installed 11.9.900.117
4. Flash Portable 11.8.800.168

**Method 2:**

1. Download and install [Adobe Flash](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) for Firefox.
2. Open Firefox and type in `about:plugins`
3. Locate the directory of the Flash plugin and copy the ff. files: `flashplayer.xpt`, `FlashPlayerPlugin_11_9_900_117.exe`(or any equivalent for that version), `NPSWF32_11_9_900_117.dll` (or any equivalent for that version)
4. Copy and paste those files to ../FirefoxPortable/Data/plugins

Comment: Be advised that LSOs (Local Shared Objects), commonly referred to as flash cookies, are still stored in a central location, depending on your OS, of course. That'd be `%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\#SharedObjects` or 
`%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys` on Windows, for instance.

Comment: Right after I last edited my question I went to my office's IT dept. to get some help about this and found another solution that does not rely on a repacked flash as a .zip.

Instead of putting that answer here and selecting it as my preferred answer, I'm just going to edit your answer to include the stuff I found out and what @JC2k8 has just mentioned. Do you mind reviewing my edit afterwards?

Comment: @SubaruTashiro Go ahead, its fine.

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied the `NPSWF32_16_0_0_305.dll` from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash` and paste it to `[YOUR_PORTABLE_APP_FOLDER]\Data\plugins`.

Comment: This worked for me on Firefox portable 48.0.1. This should be the accepted answer.